# Include html file into bokeh standalone server embed

Tags: jinja2, bokeh

How do I include a custom jinja2 html file into the Bokeh server embed sample program ? 
See:
https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.13.0/examples/howto/server_embed/standalone_embed.py
Having an html file in templates/index.html does not load by default like it does with the directory format Bokeh server.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the server embed example file:

`from jinja2 import Template`

and in the `modify_document` function add:

```
with open('./path/to/my.html') as f:
    index_template = Template(f.read())
doc.template = index_template
```

This works because the document object has a [template attribute](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/document.html)
and bokeh seems to render that for us.

Also include the bokeh variables in the jinja2 template:

```
<head>
    {{ bokeh_css }}
    {{ bokeh_js }}
</head>
```

and the body should have:

```
<body>
    {{ plot_div|indent(8) }}
    {{ plot_script|indent(8) }}
</body>
```